# Binding command of parent control to ContextMenu MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**What I'm doing:**

On my DataGrid I have a context menu to add Template items. The MenuItems are created dynamically using the ItemsSource property of the parent MenuItem. The ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection of my template objects. I want to get the Header of the dynamic MenuItems from the collection object properties, but execute a command from my main ViewModel. The main ViewModel is bound to the DataContext of the root Grid.

**My issue:**

The MenuItems are created properly and I can also bind the header to a property of an object in the collection. But the Command binding does not work. I can see an error in the output window:
"System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference..."

Here is my code reduced to the issue (using MVVM light):

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="TapTimesGui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000">
    <!-- root grid -->
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
        <!-- Jobs overview -->
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <!-- following works fine -->
                    <MenuItem Header="Basic command test" Command="{Binding AddTemplateJobCommand}" CommandParameter="Basic command test"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add template..." ItemsSource="{Binding JobTemplates}">
                        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- following command does not work System.Windows.Data Error -->
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=DataContext.AddTemplateJobCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <!--<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle> also does not work
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=DataContext.SaveDayToNewFileCommand}"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>-->
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TapTimesGui
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TapTimesGui.Services;

namespace TapTimesGui.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ...
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties and backing fields
        /// <summary>
        /// Templates for jobs
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<JobTemplate> JobTemplates
        {
            get
            {
                return _jobTemplates;
            }
        }
        private readonly ObservableCollection<JobTemplate> _jobTemplates = new ObservableCollection<JobTemplate>();
        #endregion Properties and backing fields

        #region ICommand properties
        public ICommand AddTemplateJobCommand { get; private set; }
        #endregion ICommand properties

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // assign commands
            AddTemplateJobCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(AddTemplateJob);
            // populate data on start
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO test for templates
                JobTemplate tmpJobTemplate = new JobTemplate();
                tmpJobTemplate.Name = "Template 1";
                tmpJobTemplate.Template = "TestCustomer1 AG";
                JobTemplates.Add(tmpJobTemplate);
                tmpJobTemplate = new JobTemplate();
                tmpJobTemplate.Name = "Template 2";
                tmpJobTemplate.Template = "TestCustomer2 AG";
                JobTemplates.Add(tmpJobTemplate);
            }
        }
        #endregion Constructors

        #region Command methods
        private void AddTemplateJob(string name)
        {
            //TODO implement
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage(name));
        }
        #endregion Command methods
    }
}
```

**ViewModelLocator.cs:**

```
/*
  In App.xaml:
  <Application.Resources>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TapTimesGui"
                           x:Key="Locator" />
  </Application.Resources>

  In the View:
  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModelName}"

  You can also use Blend to do all this with the tool's support.
  See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
*/

using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
//using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation; TODO http://www.mvvmlight.net/std10 chapter known issues
using CommonServiceLocator;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace TapTimesGui.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains static references to all the view models in the
    /// application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            ////{
            ////    // Create design time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Create run time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            ////}

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageHandler);
            Messenger.Default.Register<Exception>(this, ExceptionMessageHandler);
        }

        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }

        private void NotificationMessageHandler(NotificationMessage message)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message.Notification);
            MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
        }

        private void ExceptionMessageHandler(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

**JobTemplate.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TapTimesGui.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Named TapTimesGui.Model.Job template
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Can be used e.g. to save Templates of specific objects</remarks>
    public class JobTemplate : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
            }
        }
        private string _name = "";

        public string Template //Type was not string originally, it was if my Model object
        {
            get
            {
                //TODO proper cloning
                return _template;
            }
            set
            {
                //TODO proper cloning
                _template = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Template)));
            }
        }
        private string _template = "Template";
    }
}
```

**Versions:**

- Visual Studio Professional 2015
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- MvvmLight 5.4.1.1
- CommonServiceLocator 2.0.5 (required for MvvmLight)

I already tried to find a solution for some time. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `ViewModelLocator` inside the `ItemTemplate` as well.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0">
     <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="Add template..." ItemsSource="{Binding JobTemplates}">
                  <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.AddTemplateJobCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
              </MenuItem>
          </ContextMenu>
     </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

A more general approach without MVVM light could be using [a binding proxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked by using the Locator in the Binding. I will also try the binding proxy. The article of the link is very interesting and explains why it is not working.

Which way is is generally seen "nicer"?
I'm quite new to C# / WPF and very new to MVVM light.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, in case you're ever going to remove your MVVM light references, the BindingProxy is the better solution, of course.